# Why is the animation blocked at frame 1?

Tags: python, animation

I am using Python script to do off-screen CLOTH simulation. But, after I executed  `bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()`, the current frame is blocked at frame 1.

```py
C.scene.frame_start = 1
C.scene.frame_end = 50
C.scene.frame_set(1)

def stop_playback(scene):
    if scene.frame_current == 10:
        bpy.ops.screen.animation_cancel(restore_frame=False)

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(stop_playback)
#start animation
bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()

time.sleep(2)
print(C.screen.is_animation_playing) # True
print(C.scene.frame_current) # 1
time.sleep(10)
print(C.screen.is_animation_playing) # True
print(C.scene.frame_current) # 1
print('tag')
```

Comment: Consider a modal timer operator. The expectation above is   the context  is being updated by play operator  and that it will be reflected by sleeping and printing, however not the case, you are seeing the context as set in script to frame 1. Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95335/time-delay-when-selecting-objects-in-a-python-script  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131913/need-help-moving-a-set-of-cubes-from-one-end-to-the-other-on-x-axis-with-python

Comment: btw can bake a cloth sim eg  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6249/setting-the-context-for-cloth-bake without playing animation. ...